# Why does the PowerShell throws the error "The term 'My.App' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet"

Tags: powershell

Below is the script:

`powershell "[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = 'tls'; irm https://sample.website.com/detect.ps1?$(Get-Random) | iex; detect" --website.url=https://company.software.com --website.api.token=somestring== --detect.project.name="[POS] - My Sample Application (My.App) 1.0.0" --detect.project.version.name="1.1.1.1" --website.trust.cert=true --website.proxy.host=proxy.company.com --website.proxy.port=8080 --detect.detector.search.depth=10 --detect.project.user.group=WebApplication`

I am not sure if I need to escape the characters mentioned in the parenthesis.

Comment: Try to separate the lines of code using newlines. As it is written now, where you have slammed it all into a single line, the code is not readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have escaped the string from `detect.project.name` as below and it worked fine.

`detect.project.name="[POS]' '-' 'My' 'Sample' 'Application' ('My.App') '1.0.0"`